# Python: For loop for a hundred images to display depending on the position

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a camera (Gravity: HuskyLens) with a coordinate system (0,0) to (320, 240), I use them to know the position of a person's face (if it is to the left or to right) and I have a hundred images.

I get there by making my code image by image with `Tkinter` and `PIL`:

```
Left_1 = PhotoImage(file = 'Left_1.jpg')
Middle = PhotoImage(file = 'Middle.jpg')
Right_1 = PhotoImage(file = ('Right_1.jpg')

while True:
    blocks = hl.requestAll() # Camera request for Blocks and Arrows

    for block in blocks: # for loop
        if block.type == "BLOCK": # Check if a block is detected
            # Left 1 [ | | | |x| | | | | | ]
            if block.x >= 120 and block.x <= 149: # If face between (120,0) and (149, 0) display this image
                Right = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = Right_1) # PosX, PosY, Anchor, Image
                screen.update_idletasks()
                screen.update()
                time.sleep(0.5)
            # Middle [ | | | | |x| | | | | ]
            if block.x >= 150 and block.x <= 160: # If face between (150,0) and (160, 0) display this image
                Middle = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = Middle) # PosX, PosY, Anchor, Image
                screen.update_idletasks()
                screen.update()
                time.sleep(0.5)
            # Right 1 [ | | | | | |x| | | | ]
            if block.x >= 170 and block.x <= 199: # If face between (170,0) and (199, 0) display this image
                Left = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = Left_1) # PosX, PosY, Anchor, Image
                screen.update_idletasks()
                screen.update()
                time.sleep(0.5)
            
mainloop()
```

I would like to know if it was possible to display the correct image depending on the position of the person (this is an image of a character looking in the direction of the person).

But I would like to know if it is possible to do something cleaner with a `for` loop given that I have a hundred images x3 (3 characters)

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep` when using `tkinter`. Why do you have it anyways?

Comment: If you only need blocks with `block.type == "BLOCK"`, why don't you use `hl.learnedBlocks()` or `hl.blocks()` instead?  Also better to use `.after()` instead of while loop.

Comment: canvas has `itemconfig` or things like `coords`. i'm wondering that nobody says that you are creating this stuff other 100 times. if you are creating you canvas while a loop you will get trouble with the performance

Comment: @acw1668 I'm a beginner so I certainly used it badly but the last few times I used `.after()` it wasn't doing what I wanted, my whole program was running as it should with a `while` so I didn't look any further far

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to load 300 images into memory.

Instead, how about something like

```
    for block in blocks:  # for loop
        if block.type == "BLOCK":  # Check if a block is detected
            image_index = int(block.x / 10)
            image = PhotoImage(f"image_{image_index}.jpg")
            canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=image)
            # ...
```

This assumes the images are named `image_0.jpg`, `image_1.jpg`, etc.

Comment: The `screen.update_idletasks()` is useless if you have `screen.update()` just after it.

Comment: @TheLizzard I'm not a Tkinter person much at all, just copied that from OP's code. Removed it from here since it's irrelevant for the idea.

Comment: you will get problems, if you create canvas in a loop, you schould do outside it, and make `itemconfigs` or things like that

Comment: @JoeMo What problems?

Answer (score 0):

Place all the photos in a single folder along with the python file. All must have the same extensions (eg - .png). Then type this in the python file -

```
Dir = # The Folder Directory
a = 0
b = 0

import os
for file in os.listdir("Dir"):
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        img = os.path.join("Dir", file)
        Image = canvas.create_image(a, b, image = img)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        Image.delete('all')
```

Modify this according to your program
This will automatically get all images and show it

Comment: I don't know if I understand your code correctly, but it will display the images at different positions on the screen? Because I want it to be superimposed (it is the eyes of my characters that move according to the position of the person)

Comment: Please tell me do you want that image changed to a new one or add it next to the previous one?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, as long as it's as smooth as possible, but I think changing them would be less burdensome than keeping them one on top of the other

Comment: This might be what you are looking for

Comment: The `img` of `image=img` inside `create_image(...)` should be an instance of `PhotoImage()`, not image path.  Also should `Image.delete("all")` be `canvas.delete("all")` instead?

Comment: Well technically yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Assume those hundred of images x 3 (left, middle and right) are named as:

- `<blockID>_L.jpg` for left side of person identified by `blockID`
- `<blockID>_M.jpg` for middle side of person identified by `blockID`
- `<blockID>_R.jpg` for right side of person identified by `blockID`

Also it is better to use `.after()` to replace the while loop as while loop will block tkinker from updating.

Below is an example on using `.after()` to show the detected person:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
...

def update(blocks=[]):
    if len(blocks) == 0:
        blocks = hl.requestAll()
    pos = None # assume no person detected
    if blocks:
        block = blocks.pop() # extract one block record
        if block.type == "BLOCK":
            if 120 <= block.x <= 149:
                pos = "L"
            elif 150 <= block.x <= 160:
                pos = "M"
            elif 170 <= block.x <= 199:
                pos = "R"
    if pos:
        # load the corresponding image based on block.ID and block.x
        imagefile = f"{block.ID:03}_{pos}.jpg"
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=imagefile)
        canvas.itemconfigure(imgbox, image=image)
        canvas.image = image # save a reference of the image
        delay = 500  # update image again half a second later
    else:
        delay = 10
    root.after(delay, update, blocks)

...

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

imgbox = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw")

update() # start the update task
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's `blocks.pop()` ? Never saw it in the huskylib

Comment: No, it is a function on `list`.

Comment: Then why my output is:  'Block' object has no attribute 'pop'
 ? I have something to import or somehting like this ?Sorry I'm a little slow to understand everything

Comment: Can you show the output `print(blocks)` after `blocks = hl.learnedBlocks()`?

Comment: <huskylib.Block object at 0x756b74f0>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "v2_Eyes.py", line 74, in <module>

    update() # start the update task

  File "v2_Eyes.py", line 47, in update

    block = blocks.pop() # extract one block record

AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'pop'

Comment: Looking into the library code, `learnedBlocks()` returns the first record.  I have updated my answer using back `requestAll()` as I think `learnedBlocks()` will raise exception if no record is returned by the library.